# Django - Exception Type: NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, exception, types, reverse

hi guys im learning django but im getting this error and i dont know how to fix it, can you help me please? python 3.x /  django 1.9

im getting this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'categoria' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.9.1
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'categoria' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Exception Location: C:\Users\Yiyeh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 508
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Yiyeh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.5.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Yiyeh\\Documents\\Ejercicios\\Python\\puls\\puls',
 'C:\\Users\\Yiyeh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\python35.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Yiyeh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Yiyeh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Yiyeh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32',
 'C:\\Users\\Yiyeh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 27 Jan 2016 17:52:56 -0300

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
from datetime import datetime
from app.models import *
```

this is my view.py

```
def home(request):
    categorias = Categoria.objects.all()
    enlaces = Enlace.objects.all()
    template = "index.html"
    #diccionario = {"categorias": categorias,"enlaces":enlaces}
    return render_to_response(template,locals())
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', 'app.views.home', name='home'),
]
```

and index.html ( error on line 30 )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" 
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

    <title>Puls3: Comunidad online de gente pro y (no sé que más escribir)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/estilos.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/responsive.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- comentario de lo que sea -->
    <header>
        <figure id="logo">
            <img src="logo.png" />
        </figure>
        <h1 id="titulo_header">Puls3: Comunidad de gente cool, atractiva y millonaria</h1>
        <figure id="avatar">
            <img src="avatar.jpg" />
            <figcaption></figcaption>
        </figure>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li id="flechita_nav"><a href="/"></a></li>
            {% for cat in categorias %}
                <li><a href="{% url "categoria" cat.pk %}">{{cat}}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
            <li id="publicar_nav"><a href="{% url "add" %}">Publicar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <aside id="bienvenida">
        {% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <h2>Hola, registrate!</h2>
        <p>Es importante registrarte porque LOL!</p>
        <a id="registro" href="#">Registrate acá</a>
        <p id="mensaje_registro">En serio, registrate por favor</p>
        {% endif %}
    </aside>
    <section id="contenido">
        {% if enlaces %}

        {% for enlace in enlaces %}
        <article class="item">
            <figure class="imagen_item">
                <img src="imagen.jpg" />
            </figure>
            <h2 class="titulo_item">
                <a href="{{enlace.enlace}}">{{enlace.titulo}}</a>
            </h2>
            <p class="autor_item">
                Por <a href="#">{{enlace.usuario}}</a>
            </p>
            <p class="datos_item">
                <a class="tag_item" href="#">{{enlace.categoria}}</a>
                <span class="fecha_item">Hace <strong>{{enlace.timestamp|timesince}}</strong> min</span>
                <a class="guardar_item" href="#"></a>
            </p>
            <p class="votacion">
                <a class="up" href="{% url "plus" enlace.pk %}"></a>
                {{enlace.votos}}
                <a class="down" href="{% url "minus" enlace.pk %}"></a>
            </p>
        </article>
        {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            NO HAY ENLACES GUARDADOS
        {% endif %}
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p><strong>Powered by Platzi!</strong></p>
        <p>Mejorando.la 2013 ®</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you don't have an url pattern for categoria

Comment: I don't know what put you up to using `locals()`, but it's a bad habit. You should use the explicit dictionary that you've commented out.

Comment: i tried using diccionario = {"categorias": categorias,"enlaces":enlaces} but im getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your template is trying to create hyperlinks but you don't have corresponding entries in the `urls.py` file. Whenever you are creating a link (e.g., `href="{% url 'categoria' cat.pk %}"` django will look into `urls.py` for a `url` with the name `categoria` which takes one parameter - in this case that would be the primary key. So to get it working, you will have to have an entry looking something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # other url entries...
    url(r'^categoria/([0-9]+)/$', views.categoria_view, name='categoria'),
]
```

The `name` argument is used when reversing a url. More in the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Note that you will have to create entries for all names that you are using in the `{% url %}` tags (e.g., categoria, plus, minus, add).

Comment: Thanks for the clue, just saved me pain.